# What tool is my best bet for threaded Haskell debugging today?

Tags: haskell, multithreading, debugging

Erlang's got its multi-process debugger that let's you see all your processes. Anything similar in Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two wonderful, world class tools:

- ThreadScope, http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/threadscope/
- DTrace, http://justtesting.org/profiling-garbage-collection-in-haskell-with

ThreadScope is by far and away the best tool for thread profiling I've seen in any non-HPC setting.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Concurrent Haskell Debugger](http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~fhu/chd/), which has existed since 2002 and which works with up-to-date ghcs.  I've never used, nor heard any reports of experience using it, but it sounds like the right sort of thing.

CHD is about stepping backwards from deadlocks and so on.  It's not the kind of control panel you get with Erlang, which I'm somewhat confident doesn't exist for Haskell.